# IP address multiple access 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, html, apache, web-applications

In my program, after user upload some files(e.g.images named '00-40'), the backend is going to process them and storing them into another directory. Then when dragging the slide bar, these images will be accessed and display.

It is works fine on localhost, but when I put it on server(Apache), if I drag bar too fast I will get 403 forbidden for those images IP address on the server.`'GET XHR http://......... 403 forbidden'` I have tried on Chrome, Firefox, Safari. They all get the same situation, and sometimes even javascript libraries are 403 forbidden(happens on Safari).

I have searched for some reason, by my understanding, it might because same IP address is access too many times in a period (each drag will access that image IP address).

Does anyone have some idea to solve that? Or any suggestion, is it because apache setting?

```
( "#SliceNumber_1" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 0,
            max: stackImageIds.length-1,
            value: 0,

            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#rangeSlice_1" ).html( ui.value );
                currentSliceNumber_1=ui.value;   
                after_underlay(stackImageIds[currentSliceNumber_1]);
       //1.This 'stackImageIds[currentSliceNumber_1]' is an ip address corresponding the specific image  e.g http://servername/project/folder/image00.dcm
            },
            create: function (event, ui) {

                $("#rangeSlice_1").html($(this).slider("value"));
            }

function after_underlay(){
      cornerstone.loadImage(stackImageIds[currentSliceNumber_1]).then(function(image) {
//2. and this loadImage(cornerstone library)will access that ip address and then return a promise  
            cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);

        });
     }
```

above code will give you some explanation that how IP address will be accessed.

Comment: Most likely they're not processed at the server!? Can you post [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a link to a demo website?

Comment: Sure, I'd like to